# Skeptical Travel questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

I stumbled upon a peculiarity... Considering whether to VtC a question as off-topic, I was presented with the following:

[image]

And the link goes to meta.Skeptics.

I confirmed this wasn't just a browser cache issue by reproducing in two browsers.

Although considering the two close votes for the "claims are not widely heard" reason, I have to wonder if this bug is happening to everyone.  It is possible that two other Voters just didn't read closely, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I was off by a row filling these in. Fixed.